# pydantic model dynamic field data type

Tags: python, parsing, pydantic

I want to assign field data type dynamically based on specific conditions. Below are my models:

```
class Connection(BaseModel):
    name: str
    # type can be GCS or ORACLE
    type: str
    details: GCSDetails/OracleDetails

class GCSDetails(BaseModel):
    bucket: str
    folderName: str

class OracleDetails(BaseModel):
    host: str
    port: int
    user: str
```

So, based on "type" i.e. GCS or ORACLE how do I dynamically change the "details" data type during validation?

Answer (score 2):

`Pydantic` could do this without using an additional `type` field by means of the  `Union` type, [because](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#unions)

> *pydantic* will attempt to 'match' any of the types defined under `Union` and will use the first one that matches.

```
from typing import Union

from pydantic import BaseModel


class GCSDetails(BaseModel):
    bucket: str
    folderName: str


class OracleDetails(BaseModel):
    host: str
    port: int
    user: str


class Connection(BaseModel):
    name: str
    # type can be GCS or ORACLE
    type: str
    details: Union[GCSDetails, OracleDetails]


test_gcs = {"name": "", "type": "GCS", "details": {"bucket": "", "folderName": ""}}
test_oracle = {"name": "", "type": "ORACLE", "details": {"host": "", "port": 15, "user": ""}}

print(Connection(**test_gcs))
print(Connection(**test_oracle))
```

Output:

```
name='' type='GCS' details=GCSDetails(bucket='', folderName='')
name='' type='ORACLE' details=OracleDetails(host='', port=15, user='')
```

Comment: Your answer is absolutely correct. I would like to add one point. I guess the `type` field is needed if he wants to add validation as to whether the data actually should be of which type. I guess passing in sanitized or validated data to Union is never a good option.

Comment: Is there a way to restrict each `XXXDetails` to only specific value of `type`?

Comment: What If I want the dynamic fields in the same object (at the level of type field) ??